# undefined index while update in php issue [PLEASE HELP]

Tags: php

i had a problem in this line, because the error message tell me theres an undefined index:

```
$strSQL = " UPDATE place SET 
rating_value = '".$_POST["rating_value"]."' 
WHERE place_id = '".$_POST["place_id"]."'
";
```

pls help me if you have a solution. thanks

Comment: Store your `$_POST` variables into a single variale like `$rating_value = $_POST["rating_value"];`

Comment: Which index is undefined?

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) helps a lot for debuging

Comment: Please add the _exact_ error message to the question.

Comment: You should also check if yout `$_POST` variables exist

Comment: You probably ain't sending the _POST values

Comment: And please consider that your code is _wide open_ to sql injection attacks. Please learn about the benefits of using "prepared statements"  in combination of "parameter binding" to prevent that.

Comment: @executable excutable what should i write in the update line after i wrote $rating_value = $_POST["rating_value"];?

Answer (score -1):

Do you check your variables before do the request like :

```
if( !empty($_POST["rating_value"]) && !empty($_POST["place_id"]) ) 
{
   // your request
} else {
  echo("error");
}
```

Comment: no. the tutorial i follow is not checking the variable because the tutorial is still using under php 5. so i have to check the variable first?

Comment: @renaldykharisma you **always** have to check the variables. A rule of thumb is to **never** trust user's inputs. They can enter silly things, on purpose of because... well they are users.